# Arduino POST ERROR bad Request-Line `'

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra, arduino, http-post

I am making a web application to host JSON data POSTed from an Arduino to be hashed and stored in a database.

I am having an issue with the POST request to the web app being sent from the Arduino but I can't put my finger on it.

The error being received:

```
[28/Sep/2013:15:43:01 CDT] "POST /json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /json

[2013-09-28 15:43:06] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.

[28/Sep/2013:15:43:06 CDT] "" 400 0
```

The Arduino POST:

```
if (client.connect(server, 4567)) {
 Serial.println("connected");
 // Make a HTTP request:
 client.println("POST /json HTTP/1.1");
 client.println("User-Agent: Arduino");
 client.println("Host: localhost:4567");
 client.print("Accept: *"); client.print("/"); client.println("*");
 client.println("Content-Length: 15");
 client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 client.println("");
 client.println("{\"plot\":\"85.1\"}");
 client.println("");
}
```

I am using Ruby with Sinatra for the web app.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE></HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <H1>Bad Request</H1>
 bad Request-Line `'.
 <HR>
 <ADDRESS>
 WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-06-27) at
 localhost:4567
 </ADDRESS>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need that last client.println(""). Not sure if that's enough to cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: That did get rid of some of the crazy HTTP response characters but it is still giving the error. I'll add the HTTP response in the orig post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the `Content-Length` value is wrong - you are sending more data than that.

If you remove the last `client.println("");` as it isn't needed, and increase `Content-Length` to either 16 or 17 (depends on what newline chars `println` adds) then it works.

A more portable approach would be to build the data you want to post in a `String` object, then set the `Content-Length` based on its `.length()`.